# Symfony $form->createView causes Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in browser

Tags: php, symfony

Our controller method creates a form object and passes $form->createView() to the view data. Monolog captures a few debug messages, but no error or response is produced.

We are using symfony 2.3.12.

The problem does not occur on my local MAMP environment but does occur on a vagrant box, and our production/staging servers.

My guess is it's something specific with our environments but I'm hoping someone has experienced and solved this before.

Also this gist includes the controller, a model object and FormType.
https://gist.github.com/jeremymoore/453edcdbc3236f8e25b8

Any ideas?

**dev.log or prod.log looks like this:**

```
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] request.INFO: Matched route "ir_compare_select" (parameters: "_controller": "IR\CameraBundle\Controller\CompareController::irCompareAction", "_route": "ir_compare_select") [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 15:13:04] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
```

**Error message seen in Chrome:**
other browsers show similar messages

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your controller action please? On the Vagrant / Prod / Staging Servers are you running the production (app.php) environment or development (app_dev.php) environment?

Comment: Just updated the question to include a link to a gist.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of errors in an error_log or similar? Generally I have found that ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE will be a fatal error in the code, but i've just checked your code manually and also put it through a linter and nothing was brought up. In the web directory there should be a config.php file, have you ran that on the bad servers and seen if it flags anything up configuration wise?